# ChartJS Annotation line on stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I cannot get the annotation line to work on a stacked Bar Chart.

Example JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/cledwyn/rd5q6Lsz/10/

I have the standard Annotation per https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/charts/bar.html

```
const annotation2 = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleID: 'x',
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'black',
  value: 8,
  label: {
    rotation: 'auto',
    position: 'start',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    content: 'Line at x=Label 5',
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

but when I stack the bar charts

```
      scales: {
        xAxes: { stacked: true },
        yAxes: { stacked: true }
      },
```

then the annotation line just goes from one corner of the chart to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cledwyn/rd5q6Lsz/10/), you can see the following warning on the console.

```
"No scale found with id 'x' for annotation 'annotation2'"
```

Therefore, changing `scales.xAxes` to `scales.x` should solve part of your problem.

```
scales: {
  x: { stacked: true },
  y: { stacked: true }
}
```

You'll further have to add missing labels to `data.labels` and adjust `annotation2.value`.

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3',  'Label 4', 'Label 5'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'one',
    data: [14, 21, 4, 5, 7],
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
  }, {
    label: 'two',
    data: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5],
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 199, 132)'
  }, {
    label: 'three',
    data: [7, 1, 9, 6, 7],
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 32)'
  }]
};

const annotation2 = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleID: 'x',
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'black',
  value: 4,
  label: {
    rotation: 'auto',
    position: 'start',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    content: 'Line at x=Label 5',
    enabled: true
  }
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: {
          annotation2,
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    },
  },
};

const chart = new Chart('chart', config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.4.0/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="110"></canvas>
```